# Why does SUM from one table rises if I do an INNER JOIN with another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I can't figure this out... If I write this query...

```
SELECT SUM(d.Quantity)
FROM Invoice i
INNER JOIN InvDet d ON i.InvoiceId = d.InvoiceId
```

I get the SUM that I want, but if I do an inner join with another table I get much larger sum.

```
SELECT SUM(d.Quantity)
FROM Invoice i
INNER JOIN InvDet d ON i.InvoiceId = d.InvoiceId
INNER JOIN WorkOrder wo ON d.InvDetId = wo.InvDetId
```

I was expecting for quantity sum to remain the same, how can it be that when I make another join that the sum gets bigger? More importantly, what can I do to get desired results?

Comment: Adding the additional table might produce a result set with **more rows** being returned (if that relationship to `WorkOrder` on `InvDetId` is an 1:n relationship) - and thus if you sum over more rows - the value will be higher.

Comment: I don't really understand why it works like that, because values from InvDet stay the same, if anything, I could understand if sum was smaller with inner join. What can I do to get the value from first query but also retrieve some information from WorkOrder?

Answer (score 2):

> I want to join WorkOrder, because that table allows me to see what
> type of work was done.

The join can multiply out rows where there are multiple rows for that `InvDetId` in `WorkOrder` and then you are summing the multiplied out values.

You need to do the aggregation before the join. e.g. as below

```
SELECT i.*,
       wo.*,
       d.SumQuantity
FROM   Invoice i
       INNER JOIN (SELECT InvoiceId,
                          InvDetId ,
                          SUM(d.Quantity) AS SumQuantity
                   FROM   InvDet
                   GROUP  BY InvoiceId,
                             InvDetId ) d
               ON i.InvoiceId = d.InvoiceId
       INNER JOIN WorkOrder wo
               ON d.InvDetId = wo.InvDetId
```

Answer (score 1):

Every time you make a join with a new table you give a condition. Based on that condition new rows are matched from both tables. It looks like the relation between `InvDet` and `WorkOrder` is `one to many` and if this is the case you have repeated `InvDet` rows. For instance there is a table `order(order_id, date)` and a table `item(item_id, order_id, description)`. An order can have multiple items so when I join those tables I will have something like the following:

```
order_id, date, item_id, description
0000001   2020     1         Foo 
0000001   2020     2         Goo 
0000001   2020     3         Boo
```

Note that the field `order_id` and `date` are the same in all 3 rows. This is due the relation between the tables which is `one to many`. If was trying to sum the amount of projects I would get 3 but I actually have only one project.

To solve you problem you can use the `GROUP BY` clause to group the results based on a common column. For you case it looks like it is the `InvoiceId`. Your final query would be:

```
SELECT SUM(d.Quantity)
FROM Invoice i
INNER JOIN InvDet d ON i.InvoiceId = d.InvoiceId
INNER JOIN WorkOrder wo ON d.InvDetId = wo.InvDetId
GROUP BY i.InvoiceId
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If your table item also has a quantity field, and you'd choose to include that info, you would still get the same quantity for your items, regardless of are you just doing the sum on quantity in items table or sum on quantity of items in items table joined by order table? I've tried adding group by, and then I get values for individual InvoiceId, but when I sum those values I still get sum from second query.

Comment: The query I provided will sum all `quantity` that has the same `i.InvoiceId`. In my example if I used a sum I would be able to sum all the item quantity that belong to the same order.
@Janko could you describe what you want to query? Like I want to know the how many items is in an order

Comment: I want to know how many items are on all orders, I just need one number, which my first query will provide. But then I want to join WorkOrder, because that table allows me to see what type of work was done. Then I can make a group by type of work, but prerequisite is to first get correct quantity from InvDet.